# Elasticsearch NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Currently I started using Elasticsearch wrapper for c# "NEST", and I'm facing some troubles for writing queries that check for partial similarities such as in "book" and "books", so when I have a document that contains "books", if I search for "book" it doesn't find it:
here is my code :

```
var articles = client.Search<ProductResult>(s => s
        .From(0)
        .Size(1000)
        .MatchAll()
        .Query(q => q.QueryString(d => d
        .Query(query)
            )));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try analyzing your fields with a stemming analyzer like `snowball` which will try it's best to reduce words to their root form.  For example, `books` and `booking` => `book`, `jumps` and `jumping` => `jump`. etc...  The algorithm behind it isn't perfect and will trip up on irregular words/plural forms, but for the most part it works very well (on most European languages).

You can apply different analyzers when you initially create your index, or on an existing index using the update mapping API.  Either way, you'll have to reindex our documents to apply the new analysis.

Create index example using NEST:

```
client.CreateIndex("yourindex", c => c
    ...
    .AddMapping<YourType>(m => m
        .MapFromAttributes()
        .Properties(ps => ps
            .String(s => s.Name("fieldname").Analyzer("snowball"))
            ...
        )
    )   
);
```

Update mapping example:

```
client.Map<YourType>(m => m
    .MapFromAttributes()
    .Index("yourindex")
    .Properties(ps => ps
        .String(s => s.Name("fieldname").Analyzer("snowball"))
        ...
    )
);
```

Here's some really great info on [algorithmic stemmers in The Definitive Guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/algorithmic-stemmers.html#algorithmic-stemmers).

Comment: Thank you so much for you response @GregMarzouka, I will try it and see what I can have. Please if you have any more detailed resources on using NEST, I will appreciate sharing them with me because I see that the documentation provided on their website is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

U can use Fuzzy also...

```
var articles = client.Search<ProductResult>(s => s
            .From(0)
            .Size(1000)
            .Query(q => q.(d => d
                .Fuzzy(fz => fz.OnField("field").Value("book").MaxExpansions(2))
                ));
```

Comment: the MaxExpansion value can be changed...a bigger value means that the difference between database value and input is bigger. do some tests

Comment: also you can use the queryString with wildcard and you will search for something like this: "book*"